# Android Service for listening phone calls doesn't run continuously

Tags: android, service

I have a **`Service`** that listens to both incoming and outgoing calls.The **`Service`** runs when the app is started and keeps on running for some time even after the app is closed.But somehow is the **`Service`** is destroyed or something later.I have put **`START_STICKY`** as the return of the **`startCommand()`** method.I know the System kills the Service when the memory is high.But then how are the call recording apps able to listen to calls continuously?Is there a work around for this kind of problem?How do I make my app listen to phone calls continuously?

**Code**

**PhoneListenerService.class**

```
public class PhoneListenerService extends Service{
    private TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
    private File file;
     OutgoingReceiver outgoingReceiver;
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        outgoingReceiver=new OutgoingReceiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
        registerReceiver(outgoingReceiver,intentFilter);
        file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
        telephonyManager=(TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"AutoCall");
        if (!file.exists())
        {
            Log.e("File","Created");
            file.mkdir();
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("File",file.getPath());
        }
        telephonyManager.listen(new TeleListener(getApplicationContext(),file.getAbsolutePath()),PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        Log.e("Oncreate","Service");

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.e("OnCommand","Service");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(outgoingReceiver);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public class OutgoingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public OutgoingReceiver()
        {

        }
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e("Out","Track");
            String phone_number=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            Toast.makeText(context,"Outgoing call identified",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: declare your broadcast in the manifest - you dont have to use `registerReceiver` in the `Service`

Comment: By declaring in manifest it only works till the app is active

Comment: no, by using `registerReceiver` it only works till the app is active

Comment: Will it be still active if the device is rebooted

Comment: see [manifest-declared receivers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html#manifest-declared_receivers)

Answer (score 0):

Start the service as FOREGROUND Service like this

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Register your reporting alarms here.
    Log.e("SmsAndCallService", "IN onStartCommand");

    startForeground(105, getCompatNotification());
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

private Notification getCompatNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "105");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name) + " running").setTicker("Recording");
    Intent intent = new Intent(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 2003, intent, 0);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    return notification;
}
```

So system cant kills this service when system run out of resources. `

FOREGROUND SERVICE means some sort of notification stuff keep showing to make the system to aware that service is still running.

Comment: Notification may be shown only when call is being recorded

Comment: do you want to record call?

Comment: Yea.I use MediaRecorder for that.I have a question.If the deveice is restarted will the service and receiver still run in the background

Comment: the receiver will work but not sure about the service. but I have worked on the similar app.

Answer (score 0):

Use a static system define broadcast receiver for incoming calls.don't forgot to declare this in manifest

Answer (score 0):

> Yea.I use MediaRecorder for that.I have a question.If the deveice is restarted will the service and receiver still run in the background

Like this way you need to have broadcast receiver for reboot restarting your service and jobscheduler for Higher versoin than marshmallow Android 6.0

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Intent iService = new Intent(context, PhotoService.class);
            context.startService(iService);
        } else
            JobInfoServ.scheduleJob(context);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.your.package.broadcast.BootReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```